# How to call class static function directly

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

let's say I have something like this:

**Header.h:**

```
namespace detail {

    template <typename T>
    class HiddenClass {

        /* Bunch of things... */

        template <typename ...ArgList>
        static HiddenClass<T> & function (const ArgList & ... argTail) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to call `detail::HiddenClass<T>::function(***);` but as you can see this is ridiculous. Not to mention that this function is supposed to be a part of the user interference. I can not expect "user" of my code to write `detail::HiddenClass<T>::function(***);` whenever he\she want to call `function(***);`

**I Tried:**

```
template <typename T>
using detail::HiddenClass<T>::function;
```

And other approaches like this but i failed miserably...

**Anyone can help somehow? Advice something**

Comment: Alias it perhaps - create a global wrapper function and make the complex call from it?

Comment: Sounds like a doctor doctor situation. If you don't like your names, change them. E.g. why put the user interface into a namespace `detail`? Why call something that's public `Hidden`?

Comment: performance penalty?

Comment: @KerrekSB Because in THE madness of madness I decided to make everything in `HiddenClass` private (even constructors...). The last thing that survived was that static `function(***)`, and `friend` function can not call private constructors.

Comment: Assuming you think about wrapper functions as mentioned by @PiotrTrochim, compilers these days are very good at optimizations and inlining. A small inline function calling the real function will add little (if any!) overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a macro which will short the calling syntax:

```
#define MY_FUNCTION(Type, Arg) detail::HiddenClass<Type>::function(Arg)
```

Then, its using from the global namespace will be much shorter, and no need of `using`:

```
HiddenClass<SomeType>& rc = MY_FUNCTION(SomeType, argTail);
```